# Filtering multiple arrays

Tags: xcode

I am trying to filter 4 arrays but I can't make it work. This is a pushed tableview that uses NSString to populate. When I type something in the search bar, the search results are from 1 Array(MARLINS) even in the others. I know the problem is in `-(void)filtertContentForSearchText:`. What am I missing?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [self.searchResults2 count];
    }
    else
    {
        if ([testName isEqualToString:@"CES"])
            return [self.CES count];

        if ([testName isEqualToString:@"MARLINS"])
            return [self.MARLINS count];

        if ([testName isEqualToString:@"DELTA 2, NAVIGATOR"])
            return [self.DELTA count];

        if ([testName isEqualToString:@"CREW 2002, NAVIGATOR"])
            return [self.CREW count];
    }

    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifire = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifire];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifire];

    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        if ([testName isEqualToString:@"CES"]) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.CES objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        else if ([testName isEqualToString:@"MARLINS"]) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.MARLINS objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        else if ([testName isEqualToString:@"DELTA 2, NAVIGATOR"]) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.DELTA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        else if ([testName isEqualToString:@"CREW 2002, NAVIGATOR"]) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.CREW objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}


#pragma Search Methods

-(void)filtertContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];

    self.searchResults2 = [ self.MARLINS filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    self.searchResults2 = [ self.CES filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    self.searchResults2 = [ self.CREW filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    self.searchResults2 = [ self.DELTA filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filtertContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: in your filterContentForSearchText: method, shouldn't there be some test to only set self.searchResults2 once (for the self.ARRAY that you want)? In the code you posted, you're setting it 4 times (and overriding it).

Comment: yes, but i have 4 arrays. i don't know another method.

Comment: You have the scope parameter that you're not using inside the filter method. Pass in something useful there from shouldReloadTableForSearchString: to know which array you should be filtering.

Comment: i don't know how to do that

Comment: You may already be doing part of it. Look at your shouldReloadTableForSearchString: method. You're passing in a value for scope. Look at that variable. If that variable is something you can use to identify which array you want to use, then at the bare minimum, you can replicate your if...else block similar to the code you have in cellForIndexPath and only filter a particular array.

Comment: thank you!!!! i have done it!

Answer (score 0):

(Extracting from comments into an 'answer', edited slightly to flow together better):

You have the scope parameter that you're not using inside the filter method. Pass in something useful there from shouldReloadTableForSearchString: to know which array you should be filtering.

Look at that scope variable. If its existing value is something you can use to identify which array you want to use, then at the bare minimum, you can replicate your if...else block similar to the code you have in cellForIndexPath and only filter a particular array.